# Can Fury Bowser be defeated with only Cat Shines?

Tags: bowsers-fury

In Bowser’s Fury, collecting a Cat Shine while Fury Bowser is present will lower his health for when you fight him as giant Cat Mario.

Is it possible to collect enough Cat Shines to fully drain Fury Bowser’s HP? If so, what happens? Does it skip the Kaiju-inspired boss fight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is impossible to defeat Fury Bowser solely by collecting Cat Shines, due to the damage stopping once he reaches one point of health

The above text is from the Super Mario Wiki and is available under a Creative Commons license. Attribution must be provided through a list of authors or a link back to the original article. Source: https://www.mariowiki.com/Fury_Bowser#Behavior